# Can someone tell me where to get a good look into Dot Notation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, notation

Been searching for about an hour, everything I see on dot notation is pieced out with little explanation, or it's a post of people arguing about that and bracket notation... I just want a  site or book, I will buy a book... 
...that has a lot of info on Dot Notation. Thanks for taking a look at my post!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [this link](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html)?

There is also the [ECMAScript documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) that indicates:

The dot notation is explained by the following syntactic conversion:

```
MemberExpression.IdentifierName
```

is identical in its behaviour to

```
MemberExpression[<identifier-name-string>]
```

Also see the Objects section of [this javascript article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html) written by Douglas Crockford.